# Query in MySQL database taking a long time

Tags: mysql

I have a query in mysql database, it returns only 50 records but took 18 seconds to execute, here is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.UniqueNo, a.TorrentFilename, d.DataValue As Size
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT aa.UniqueNo, aa.TorrentFilename, aa.UploadDate
      FROM TorrentList aa INNER JOIN
           UploadList b
           ON aa.UniqueNo = b.UniqueNo INNER JOIN
           Minifile c
           ON aa.UniqueNo = c.UniqueNo
      ORDER BY aa.UploadDate DESC LIMIT 1, 50
     ) a LEFT JOIN
     TorrentInfo d
     ON a.UniqueNo = d.UniqueNo AND d.DataName='Size'
ORDER BY a.UploadDate DESC
```

What is the problem of the query? I have optimized it a lot but it seems no effect. If I use MS SQL, it took only a few miliseconds to execute it, is it something wrong with MySQL?

Comment: How many rows do you have in TorrentInfo Table?

Comment: optimizing the query is pointless if the tables you're querying don't have appropriate indexes.

Comment: create indexes , it will make queries faster.

Comment: Is it a question of your tables being indexed differently in the different systems?

Comment: I found out the problem as the answer points out that I dont have indexes in the table. After adding index it is now returning result under 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does a better job of doing joins when there are no indexes.  And is better at aggregation (which is used for `distinct`).

Your query might do better with the following indexes:

```
UpLoadList(UniqueNo)
Minifile(UniqueNo)
TorrentList(UploadDate, UniqueNo)
TorrentList(UniqueNo, DataName)
```

These don't "cover" the table.  But they should facilitate the `join`s and `order by` in the subquery.